# Where are the hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Are we getting hats this year, and if so, where and when will they be announced?

I am told that my first draft (the sentence above) did not meet ELU's quality standards.  Funny, I thought brevity was the soul of wit.  Well, to pad things so that my question completely describes my problem:  Are we getting hats this year, and if so, where and when will they be announced?

Comment: Well, I can see some users are wearing hats, so I guess they have already been announced.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list There's also a knitting competition if you're in vein https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting

Comment: @Hugo In the spirit of Christmas, I changed Q to question.  Please tell me why you object to Q -- it seems an innocent time-saver to me.

Comment: Thank you! It's an attempt to earn a hat! https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/itsa-me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hats are already on this year! It's running from  December 12th through January 1st this year. You can find a list of hats and how to get them [here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838/323179). Alternatively, you can go directly to the Winter Bash site [here](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/).

(Anyways, [knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319846/323179) is where it's at this year.)

Make sure that you don't hate hats by clicking on the snowflake in the top right. If you see something like the following you need to click on the "I Love Hats" button and then there will be HATS:

[image]

Comment: But if, as I have been told, the standarising of sites was primarily made to save running costs, shouldn’t season’s hats, on the same premise, have been abolished too?

Comment: @user240918 Hats are something that's done the same way across all the sites (except for the sites that hate fun and don't have hats). It's a way for Stack Exchange to get people excited to come to the site during the time when traffic drops for the holidays. Plus they're also using it to advertise for Stack Overflow for Teams.

Comment: @user240918 Unification of themes isn't about saving running costs. It's about making the network easier to maintain when you have 170+ sites and giving the 100+ of those sites with no custom elements at all the chance for it. We can't create new features for the network without simplifying the code because every new feature breaks a good chunk of the sites, which we then spend more time fixing than making the new features... and people don't like it when their sites don't work, either. ;) This actually makes hats *easier* to implement.

Comment: @Catija - thanks for clarifying, but doesn't  "*It's about making the network easier to maintain when you have 170+ sites and giving the 100+ of those sites with no custom elements at all the chance for it.*" actually translates into lower operating and maintenance costs?

Comment: @user240918 It may be a matter of how you look at things. Yes, it's lower cost for us because we're not hiring dozens more people to be able to do both at the same time (1. maintain an absurdly complicated codebase that breaks constantly 2. continue to release new features for the site).... but that's only if you assume we're *able* to hire those people. We need to be able to work with what we have, which is limited, so we're investing in the future by taking a haphazardly-created system and restructuring it with intention and simplicity with room to iterate in the future.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes!

Hats are *here again*!

https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com

[image: Winter Bash header showing a knitted wintry scene]